# Add a Shared Album to your VISIBLE Google-Photos Albums List

Tags: google-docs, google-photos, sharing, album

Assume Bob has a Google Photo Album and it is shared out to Mary.  The two are coworkers, wherein Mary is creating a document which requires photos from the shared photo album.

Although Mary can insert photos into a Google doc from photo albums Mary creates, how can she configure the Bob's shared photo album to be available as well, so as to be accessible to from Google Docs?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 8 times. Remember that you can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The recipient must:

First: Open the email invitation and click on the blue View album button.

[image]

Next, click shared album and press a blue `join` button **if on the page**:

[image]

then click `more options`:

[image]

Next: Then select `show in albums`:

[image]

The shared album will be attached the recipient's album list.